# Web development tool -PHP/CSS/HTML

Tags: windows, gratis, html, php, css

I want to develop a website from scratch: New to web development and have basics of PHP, HTML, CSS, MYSQL.

Can anyone suggest me a best and easy tool (freeware) for website design - Specially who will automatically take care of CSS/HTML part.

I can run the code there also?
Is eclipse ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started out with [CodeLobster PHP](http://www.codelobster.com/), which is free, slightly basic, but gets the job done.

Then as started to mix C++ development with PHP, I switched to [NetBeans](https://netbeans.org/features/php/) and was happy with it for years.

I recently changed to [PHPstorm](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/) the community edition and find that I prefer that over NetBeans.

YMMV. All that I can say is that I have tried all 3 of these & found them to be good.

Comment: Please come back later and post telling us which one you chose and why, as that could help others in future.